# ng-repeat for array of object of objects

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-meteor

I am working on angular-meteor.
I have a collection called grace in the following json format

```
grace: {
    "mail-template": {
        "new-status": {
            "in-progress": {
                "name": "demo1",
                    "description": "this is demo"
            },
            "pending": {
                "name": "demo2",
                    "description": "this is another demo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am taking `in-progress` and `pending` as keys, `name` and `description` as values.

I want to list this inside my html using `ng-repeat`. But I didn't get any output and no errors found.

The code I used is

```
ng-repeat="(key,value) in demoCtrl.formSettings.grace['mail-template']['new-status']"
```

`demoCtrl` is my controller name and `formSettings` is name of helpers.
Can somebody clear my code?

Comment: Why do you need a repeater for this?

Comment: I want to list those templates plus the admin need to edit the details if he wishes to. initially the json file didn't have that new_status object.  Mail-template object had the key value pairs and this code was working perfect.

Comment: You need to debug this, put `{{ key }}` AND `{{ value | json }}` inside the `ngRepeat`. You can anso try and print `{{ demoCtrl.formSettings.grace | json }}` before the `ngReapet` to make sure everything is connected as expected and that you didn't missed anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24516/). It seems to work just fine. Make sure that you've got the correct data in the `demoCtrl.formSettings`.

**JS**

```
$scope.obj = {
    grace: {
       "mail-template": {
           "new-status": {
               "in-progress": {
                   "name": "demo1",
                       "description": "this is demo"
               },
               "pending": {
                   "name": "demo2",
                       "description": "this is another demo"
               }
           }
       }
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj.grace['mail-template']['new-status']">
    {{key}}: {{value}}
</div>
```

Comment: sorry to tell my code was working well. Like you said placed the code in a hidden div... Thanks for your effort in helping